# Vue img src path does not work the same as :src

Tags: image, vue.js, path, vuejs3

I use Vue. I try to output an image and it works fine when I use `src` but not when I use `:src`.

#### Works

```html
<img src="../assets/image.png" />
```

#### Does not work

```html
<img :src="`../assets/${image}.png`" />
```

#### What I've tried, but did not work

- `@` first in the path.
- `~` first in the path.
- `./` first in the path.
- `/` first in the path.
- `require` but it throws an error if the image can't load. I prefer the native broken image icon, which does not break the script.

#### My output

The variable `image` contains the filename which in this case would be `image`.

The output from both version is like below:

```html
<img src="../assets/image.png" data-v-469af010=""> <!-- src -->
<img src="/img/image.f556f8c5.png" data-v-469af010=""> <!-- :src -->
```

For some reason they differ quite alot.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Where does the image variable come from? Which error did you get? Your code should work.

Comment: @BülentAkgül I added the output to my question now.

Comment: This is wired, and I don't know where f556f8c5 came from. I don't understand how the base path has changed. First, where image variable came from (v-for, data object, method, computed property, prop, store)? Second, instead of img tag, add a <span>{{image}}</span> and see what is the real value.

Comment: which bundler are you using vite or vue cli ...?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes, Vue CLI and it does something magical with the `src`version as seen in the output, changing the path and add some hash id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with this:

```
<img :src="cover(url)" /> // I call a method cover.

// Method cover
cover(url) {
    if (url !== ''){ // You can check any matching expression.
         try {
             url = require('@/assets/img/' + url)
         } catch (e) {
             url = require('@/assets/img/default.jpg'); // I used a default image. 
         }
     }
     else
         url = require('@/assets/img/default.jpg'); // Default image. 
     return url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind src to the method.

```
getImgUrl(image) {
    return `../assets/${image}.png`
  }
```

in HTML

```
<img :src="getImgUrl(image)" />
```

Comment: I got the same problem, exactly the same src path as without the bind.

Comment: can you tell me what the error is if you use my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If image variable is name of file

```
<img :src="'../assets/'+image" />
```

You should not use $ in template.

Comment: That's old code. In ES5+ we can use what I did. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals